# How to split a string into list of strings in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, fold

```
split sep str = foldr op [[]] str
    where op (x:xs) (y:ys)
              | x == sep = ([]:y)
              | otherwise = ((x:y):ys)
```

I'm trying to make a string split starting from a string and getting to a list of strings. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `([]:y)` makes no sense, since it should be a list of lists of items, but `y` is a list of items.

Answer (score 1):

`([]:y)` makes no sense, since it should be a list of lists of items, but `y` is a list of items. Even if the type system would not complain (for example because of a dynamically typed language like Python), it would not make much sense, since you drop `ys`, which would thus omit the rest of the recursion.

Another problem is that you write `(x:xs)` as first parameter, which means that the items in the list you fold are lists themselves, but given I understand it correctly, you fold a `String`, so the element is simple character:

You can fix this by returning `[]:y:ys`:

```
split :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => a -> f a -> [[a]]
split sep str = foldr op [[]] str
    where op x ~(y:ys)
              | x == sep = []:y:ys
              | otherwise = (x:y):ys
```

For example:

```
Prelude> split '-' "this-is-kebab-case"
["this","is","kebab","case"]
```

Comment: Obviously this question reminds the `words` function. One thing worth noting with the `words` function is `words "           "` resulting `[]`. So coming back to this topic; what if the string only consists of separators? Such as `"------"` in your test case. While your answer being sufficient for the OP's problem, still It could be a good idea to check [words](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#words) definition :)